# In C++, is there any way to reduce the number of member functions with move semantics?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, sfinae

I am trying to write my vec class. For efficiency, I use move semantics.

```
Vec<int> v1;
Vec<int> v2;
Vec<int> v3;
Vec<int> v4;
v4 = v1 + v2;                   // Line 1
v4 = v1 + v2 + v3;              // Line 2
v4 = v1 + (v2 + v3);            // Line 3
```

But, to let each line above only calls copy constructor once, I have to overload four function with one operator. Like the codes below.

```
Vec(Myself&& v) 
{    // move consturctor
    dim = v.dim;
    value = std::move(v.value);
}

Myself& operator+= (const Myself& v)
{
    for (size_type i = 0; i < dim; ++i) (*this)[i] += v[i];
    return *this;
}

template<typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<Myself>::value>::type* = nullptr>   // SFINAE
friend Myself& operator+ (Myself&& a, const Myself& b)
{
    return a += b;
}

Myself& operator+ (Myself&& v) const
{
    return v += *this;
}

Myself operator+ (const Myself& v) const
{
    Myself ansV(*this);
    ansV += v;
    return ansV;
}
```

Thanks for **Lightness Races in Orbit**'s reminder. I added the move constructor into the codes above.

**1. Is there any way to write less functions for one operator?**

**2. Why the SFINAE is added at the function `friend Myself& operator+ (Myself&& a, const Myself& b)`, not `Myself& operator+ (Myself&& v) const`? It is used to fixed the confusion of `v4 = v1 + (v2 + v3);`.**

Comment: Where are your moves? I don't see any.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: `return v += *this;` That isn't backwards?

Comment: You have to handle 4 cases (&& + &&, && + &, & + &&, & + &) with 3 different implementation. I don't see way to do this with less than 3 methods.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What dose "backwards" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I write operators for an arithmetic class `T`, I usually do the following:

**(a) If the operation is commutative (a+b equals b+a):**

Put the implementation of `+=` into T:

```
T & T::operator+=(T const& other) {
    // [Perform the actual operation (add other to *this)]
    x += other.x; // or something similar
    return *this;
}
```

Provide the following two functions outside the class:

```
T operator+(T a, T const& b) {
    a += b;
    return a;
}

T operator+(T const& a, T && b) {
    MyInt temp(std::move(b));
    temp += a;
    return temp;
}
```

**(b) If the operation is not commutative (a-b is different from b-a):**

Put the implementation of `-=` into T and provide a second function that works on the second operand instead of the first:

```
T & T::operator-=(T const& other) {
    // [Perform the actual operation of (subtract other from *this)]
    x -= other.x; // or something similar
    return *this;
}

void T::operatorMinus(T & other) const {
    // [Perform the actual operation, but work on other instead of *this]
    other.x = x - other.x; // or something similar
}
```

Provide the following two functions outside the class:

```
T operator-(T a, T const& b) {
    a -= b;
    return a;
}

T operator-(T const& a, T && b) {
    MyInt temp(std::move(b));
    a.operatorMinus(temp);
    return temp;
}
```

**Result:**

Both gcc and clang now only need a single copy constructor in the following examples using `-O3` (same for `operator-`):

```
T a1, a2, a3, x;
x = a1 + a2;
x = a1 + a2 + a3;
x = (a1 + a2) + a3;
x = a1 + (a2 + a3);
```

Even the case where both operands are rvalues is handled without ambiguity. The following compiles fine, even though two copies are needed (one copy for `a1+a2` and one copy for `a3+a4`):

```
T a1, a2, a3, a4, x;
x = (a1 + a2) + (a3 + a4);
```

Comment: In your move addition you reverse the order of `a` and `b`: `temp += a;`. How would you implement it if there is a dependency on the order of `a` and `b`? Thus `a+b != b+a`? Edit: This is already the case for `operator-`....

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius If the operation is not commutative, you need to provide at least two implementations: The "default" implementation, just like before, and an implementation that keeps the first operand constant and works on the second one. In case of `operator-`, you may use something like `a-b = -(b-a)`, but in general (e. g. matrix multiplication) this is not trivial.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I updated my answer and included the non-commutative case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you please update your demo so that `operator=` returns a reference? Or remove the operator completely, as it is not used in your example.

Comment: Thanks. There is a small error in the minus example: you are overloading `operator+`.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: I was thinking: I'm not sure if it is good to make `operatorMinus` a public function. I'm not sure if is should be available to external users. What's your opinion?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius There is exactly one situtation where a user needs `operatorMinus`: He has two variables `a` and `b` of type `T`, he wants to compute `a-b`, and he wants to store the result in `b`. Seems pretty improbable to me. So yes, in general you want to make it private, otherwise it confuses the other users of your class.